# Can't get done Conv1D with tf.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I'm having te following model and the dataset contains 186093 time-series where each time-series is the length of 48

Tensorflow version 2.x

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(30, 4, activation=tf.nn.selu, input_shape=(train_data.shape[1], train_data.shape[0])),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(3),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(15, 2, padding='same', activation=tf.keras.activations.selu),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(3),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid)
])
```

And the model summary is as follows

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 45, 30)            22331190  
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D) (None, 15, 30)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 15, 15)            915       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 5, 15)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 75)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               9728      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 129       
=================================================================
Total params: 22,341,962
Trainable params: 22,341,962
Non-trainable params: 0
```

However, when I try to train the model as below

```
model.fit(train_data, train_result, epochs=2000, validation_split=0.2, verbose=0, callbacks=[early_stop])
```

I'm getting the following error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (186093, 48)
```

I tried to change the `input_shape` to (None, 48) as I have 48 features. But then I even can't create the model as it throws bellow error

```
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

Can someone help me to figure out what am I doing wrong here or missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in simply the shape of your data.

First things first, I'm assuming `train_data.shape[0]` gives 186093. This is the number of discrete samples. It is not the number of features in a single sample.

So change `input_shape=(train_data.shape[1], train_data.shape[0])` to
`input_shape=(train_data.shape[1], 1)`

Next,

`Conv1D` (when used for time-series) expects data of the shape [batch_size, timesteps, features]. In your case, `features` is 1.

You can therefore set the correct shape as follows (Assuming you are using `numpy`):

```
train_data = np.expand_dims(train_data, axis=-1)
```

Add this line before calling `model.fit()`